# How to pass data to a popup modal in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the logged user id in a React popup. I'm passing logged_user from MyVerticallyCenteredModal popup function call, but it is not getting when I try to print in popup.

```
<div className="about">
  <span> logged user id is : {loggedUserid} <span> //here prints id of logged user as 1
  <MyVerticallyCenteredModal logged_user={loggedUserid}
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      />
</div>



function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props,{logged_user}) {
const user_id = logged_user;
    console.log("logged in id is ", user_id); // not getting logged user id here(prints undefined)


return (
    <Modal  
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
    <div className="modal-header">
<span>My id is {user_id}</span>//  not getting logged user id here
</div>
</Modal>


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SreRoR you need to just passed `props` in your functional component then only you will access that `id` you passing from another component.

**let's take an example**

```
const loggedUserid = 1;

<MyVerticallyCenteredModal logged_user={loggedUserid} />
```

After in other function component you have to pass `props` as an argument like below

```
const MyVerticallyCenteredModal = props => {
  const user_id = props.logged_user;    // you not getting id here because you haven't add props.logged_user
  console.log("logged in id is ", user_id);

  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      <h1>
        {"user id ===>"} {user_id}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is full code [Example you can check](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eahvqg?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 1):

You passed a property value called logged_user to your functional component.

In your functional component use "props.logged_user" to access the value you passed.
So it should be:

```
function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props) {
const user_id = props.logged_user;
    console.log("logged in id is ", user_id); // not getting logged user id here(prints undefined)
```